# A lot of "implicitly-declared '[...]::operator=([...])' is deprecated" error in the Opensplice when compiling with gcc11

Tags: c++, opensplice, gcc11

I am using Opensplice library in my project and everything is working with gcc4. I am would like to compile my project with gcc11 but I get a lot of the same errors in the Opensplice section. For example:

`implicitly-declared ‘dds::core::status::SampleRejectedState& dds::core::status::SampleRejectedState::operator=(const dds::core::status::SampleRejectedState&)’ is deprecated`

I know that we should define both the assignment operator and copy constructor or neither of them in gcc11. But, how can I fix this issue for Opensplice? Can I build Opensplice again with gcc11 or I should do something else?

Comment: "... is deprecated" should be a warning not an error. Is it an error?

Comment: Yes, it is an error!

Comment: did you `-Werror` ?

Comment: gcc11 is using a different C++ standard by default. You can still use an older one `-std=c++03`. Or do you need to compile as C++11?

Comment: Yes, I used QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -Werror

Comment: fwiw, also gccs complete error message should tell you that its a warning treated as error due to `Werror`

Comment: The question is that if I add "QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += Werror=depricated-copy" to my project, then the compiled code is still correct or not yet?

Comment: It *is* correct. Deprecated is not removed. Future standard versions may disable the auto-generation in the circumstances where the warning is fired, but that hasn't happened yet to my knowledge.

Comment: @EhsanSharifiEsfahani You mean `Wno-error=depricated-copy`? The deprecation warning is just that. It has no effect on the program behavior in current C++ standards (and I have some doubts that the deprecated implicit function will ever be removed in future standard revisions).

Comment: Of course you can ask the library vendor to fix their code to not use deprecated features. It is as simply as adding `SampleRejectedState& operator=(const SampleRejectedState&) = default;`. (Assuming that the implicit assignment operator is not itself a mistake, which it often would be under the deprecation circumstances.)

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue, we can do
1- Ask the vendor to fix this issue internally
2- Disable all of these errors by removing the `-Werror` flag
3- or by adding `-Wno-deprecated-copy` or `Wno-error=depricated-copy` if want to keep `-Werror` flag.